# Rosws (ROS CVS) Tutorials link is broken?

Tags: ros, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I just wanted to point out that the link to the rosws tutorials are broken in these websites:

- [ROS > /wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)
- [ROS > /wiki/rosws](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosws)

The link that does not work is:

- [ROS > /doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws_tutorial.html](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws_tutorial.html)

I have tried to find the correct link to the tutorial, but I have had no success.
I do not know what to do about it (I am starting to use ROS), so I decided to post this question. Sorry for the cryptic webpage links, I do not have enough karma to post them.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57019/rosws-(ros-cvs)-tutorials-link-is-broken?/) by [jespestana](https://answers.ros.org/users/4328/jespestana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the rosws wiki page I found [this](http://www.ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosinstall/html/) link referring to the documentation for the "new rosws" in the "Documentation" section. Browsing the docs I found [this](http://www.ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosinstall/html/rosws.html) page which seems to be the equivalent to what you were looking for.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-03-04**:
thanks, will inestigate

**Comment by [jespestana](https://answers.ros.org/users/4328/jespestana/) on 2013-03-04**:
Thanks for the link to the tutorials website!